# How to monitor battery level while app is in background then send push notification? IOS 14

Tags: ios, c, swift

I am looking for a way to constantly monitor battery level while my app is in the background then send a notification at certain levels. Is this a possibility in Swift?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: You can't. It's not a question of the language used. It is a limitation imposed on the platform by Apple.

Most Apps don't get processor time in the background. The small number of exceptions (VoIP apps, music players, and turn-by-turn navigation apps) have to be approved by Apple.

All other apps get suspended when the user switches to another app or to the springboard. You can ask for additional background time when that happens, but that gives you a one-time extension of up to 3 minutes.

Apple goes to great lengths to **prevent** apps from running indefinitely in the background because it consumes battery power. (except for the app types I listed, where the user explicitly asks to use something like a music player or a turn-by-turn navigation app where it's understood that those apps use more battery power.)

Comment: Ah okay that's unfortunate. So i would have to send notifications based on a time interval then?